# Get count of missing and non-missing values for each column in a table in Teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table with below similar data in Teradata and I want to count the total missing and total non missing records of each column in the table.

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Currently I'm using below query

```
SELECT 'New_York' Column_Name
, SUM(CASE WHEN New_York <> ''  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Nonmissing
,SUM(CASE WHEN New_York = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Missing
from Table A

SELECT 'London' Column_Name
, SUM(CASE WHEN London <> ''  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Nonmissing
,SUM(CASE WHEN London = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Missing
from Table A
```

and so on

Can anyone please advice if there is anyway we can loop through all columns to create single query instead of repeating the same query multiple time with different column names. I have around 430 columns in the table and repeating same query multiple time is not feasible. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server <> Teradata; what are you *really* using?

Comment: I'm using Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: SQL Assistant is a ODBC front end, is Teradata your backend?

Comment: In any case,  I would build this in Excel, concatenating the file name and the statement you want to build.  Something like `concatenate("sum(case when trim(coalesce(",A1, ")) = '' then 1 else 0 end) as ..."`.  I'm probably missing parens, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @Andrew : yes I agree in excel it is easy and I did first replicate in excel, but I'm trying to create Teradata query so that we can use that in our automation. BTW backend is Oracle DB.

Comment: @Prav then remove "Teradata" tag and add "Oracle" to make it more likely you get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Its pretty generic SQL, it should work for you.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @allsql nvarchar(max) = ''

declare db_cursor cursor for
select   
    'SELECT ''' + column_name + ''' AS CityName, (select count(*) from CityNumbers where ' + column_name + ' IS NULL) AS Missing, (select count(*) from CityNumbers where ' + column_name + ' IS NOT NULL) AS NonMissing UNION ' AS sql
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = 'CityNumbers'

open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @sql

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    set @allsql = @allsql + @sql
    fetch next from db_cursor into @sql
end
close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor

select @allsql = left(@allsql,len(@allsql)-6)
select @allsql

exec (@allsql)
```

Here's the result:

| CityName | Missing | NonMissing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dubai | 3 | 2 |
| London | 2 | 3 |
| NewYork | 1 | 4 |
| Paris | 0 | 5 |
| Singapore | 1 | 4 |

Comment: Thank you for your response. This looks like more generic SQL code, when I try to use this in Teradata SQL Assistant, I'm getting error "Query is invalid". I'm looking for code which is more specific to Teradata (Teradata SQL Assistant)

Comment: That query is completely ANSI, I would be surprised if Teradata could not execute it.  I think the issue may be with SQL Assistant - it may only support queries, not cursors and procedural logic.  Do you have another way to query the database?